# jQDateRangeSlider shows the wrong dates

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-ui, jquery-plugins

I'm trying to integrate [jQDateRangeSlider](https://ghusse.github.io/jQRangeSlider/options.html#boundsOption) into my page.

The settings are as follows:

```
$("#slider").dateRangeSlider({
    defaultValues:{
            min: new Date(2014, 12, 5),
            max: new Date(2015, 1, 26)
    },
    bounds: {
            min: new Date(2014, 12, 5),
            max: new Date(2015, 1, 26)
    }
});
```

But it doesn't work: http://jsfiddle.net/oe8yk19n/

[image: lolwat]

The dates shown are 2015-01-05 ~ 2015-02-26, which are completely different from those that I've actually entered... so weird.

Its not that the slider can't span that far, because [the defaults span 2 years](https://github.com/ghusse/jQRangeSlider/blob/master/jQDateRangeSlider.js#L15).

Super strange - any ideas?

Answer (score 0):

```
$("#slider").dateRangeSlider({
    bounds: {
            min: new Date(2014, 11, 5),
            max: new Date(2015, 0, 26)
    },
    defaultValues:{
            min: new Date(2014, 11, 5),
            max: new Date(2015, 0, 26)
    }
});
```

Apparently it is because month counting starts at zero in javascript. Wat.